# PHP5-FPM Core Dumping due to some weird Zend error

Tags: php, php-fpm, dump

I am getting an extremely weird core dump, which refers back to "Not Having Zend" even though zend is installed and working properly.

This started showing up today after I did an `apt-get upgrade`, and for some reason, it's not allowing me to downgrade anymore, but it only was a minor change so I am clueless to what has changed.

Here is the core dump:

```
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www                                                       '.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x7fcb09b027d0, p=0x7fcb09b027e0) at /build/php5-oxmf3S/php5-5.6.4+dfsg/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2104
2104    /build/php5-oxmf3S/php5-5.6.4+dfsg/Zend/zend_alloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  _zend_mm_free_int (heap=0x7fcb09b027d0, p=0x7fcb09b027e0) at /build/php5-oxmf3S/php5-5.6.4+dfsg/Zend/zend_alloc.c:2104
#1  0x00000000006ac920 in sapi_deactivate () at /build/php5-oxmf3S/php5-5.6.4+dfsg/main/SAPI.c:525
#2  0x00000000006a3c35 in php_request_shutdown (dummy=<optimized out>) at /build/php5-oxmf3S/php5-5.6.4+dfsg/main/main.c:1893
#3  0x000000000046565d in main (argc=162534288, argv=0x7fcb09b01c30) at /build/php5-oxmf3S/php5-5.6.4+dfsg/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:2071
(gdb)
```

Comment: https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Reporting

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me upgrading to PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11, my stacktrace looks the same, I managed to solve it by changing the nginx configuration. This one has been working forever and it stopped working after the upgrade:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Adding the `fastcgi_param` directive helped me solve the issue, so I just added it to every website on my server:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; # This one
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

But this issue continues to be a bit weird.